Testing state in fetch custom hook
I wrote a custom hook to fetch data that is working fine but I can't test the state exposed by the hook. Specifically, I want to test that:

The loading state is false before fetching (Working)
The loading state is true while fetching (Problem: I never get true)
The loading state is false after fetching (I think it is working, but I can't be sure until I get a truthy state before)

How can I test this kind of async state inside a hook?
// useFetch.ts

import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface Props{
    endpoint: string,
}

interface FetchReturn<T> {
    result: T | null,
    loading: boolean,
    fetchLazy: (params?: any) => Promise<T | null>,
    statusCode: number,
    error: any,
};

export function useFetch<T>({ endpoint, method }: Props): FetchReturn<T> {
  const [result, setResult] = useState<T | null>(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState<any>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = useCallback((_data: any): Promise<T | null> => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    setResult(null);

    const options: any = {
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      method: method,
    };
    
    // Mostly in case of POST, PUT, PATCH & DELETE
    if (method !== 'GET' && _data !== undefined) {
      options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      options.body = JSON.stringify(_data);
    }

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      /*
       * I want to test this line!
       */
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch(endpoint, options);

      try {  
        const text = await response.text();  
        const data = JSON.parse(text);  
        if (!response.ok) {
          setError(data?.errors?.json);
          reject(error);
        } else {
          setResult(data);
          setError(null);
          setLoading(false);
          resolve(data);
        }
      } catch (err: any) {  
        setResult(null);
        setError(err);
        setLoading(false);
        reject(err);
      }
    })
  },[endpoint, method]);

  const fetchLazy = (params = {}): Promise<T | null> => {
    return fetchData(params);
  }

  return ({ result, loading, fetchLazy, statusCode, error });
}


I use it as a lazy method, so I can trigger request with arbitrary actions:
const myComp: () => {
  const { loading, fetchLazy } = useFetch({ endpoint: myEndpoint });
  await fetchLazy({ some: 'options' })
    .then((result) => {/* handle result */})
    .catch((error) => {/* handle error */});

  return <>loading: {loading}</>
}

And this is the test:
// useFetch.test.spec

import fetchMock, { enableFetchMocks } from 'jest-fetch-mock';
import { beforeEach, describe, expect, test, jest } from '@jest/globals';
import { act, renderHook, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { useFetch } from './useFetch';
enableFetchMocks();

describe.only('useFetch', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetchMock.resetMocks();
    jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch');
  });

  test.only('> fetchLazy should update loading state', async () => {
    const answer = { 'POST works': true };
    fetchMock.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(answer));
    const options = { endpoint: '/', method: 'POST', csrfToken: '0' };
    const { result: { current: hook }, rerender } = renderHook(() => useFetch(options as any));

    expect(hook.loading).toBe(false);
    await act(async () => {
      await hook.fetchLazy({ 'post': 'works?' });
      // neither this…
      expect(hook.loading).toBe(true);
    });
    // …nor this works.
    expect(hook.loading).toBe(true);
    rerender();
    expect(hook.loading).toBe(false);
  });
});


